# Get a path value in java file from html/jsp

Tags: java, html, jsp

I'm writing a web app where there is a file selection done. And in there is a java class where this path has to be printed out. In simple terms I want the file full path selected in JSP to be printed in a Java Class.

In regular java classes, we import the class1 into class2 and get the path.

But I'm unable to know how can I do this using a jsp and a java class.

In jsp, I'm using

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function setExcelPath() {

    }
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <input type="file" name="fileName" id="fileName" /> <input
            type="submit" value="Set" onclick="setExcelPath()" />

</body>
</html>
```

Here I'm able to see the textbox with the file path along with path. Please let me know how can i send this value to a java class.

I need this path since there is some other Apache POI code to be written based on this selection.

Thanks

Comment: Why do you need that path? Assuming you want to do something with the file then you'd need the file itself rather than the path which might not be accessible to the server (and AFAIK is by default not sent over anyways). As for handling the form in a Java class have a look at servlets.

Comment: +1 thomas, @OP you should upload the file not the path. Few browser's won't support you to get the file path for security reason's.

Comment: Hi @Thomas, I just need the path, For file processing, I've got another Java File. And in this Java file, I need the path

Comment: What do you actually need that path for? A path on the client's machine is not accessible in most cases and of no use on the server anyways. What do you do with that path if it doesn't exist on the server (quite likely) and the server can't poll that path on the client (also quite likely)?

Comment: This path is just to know where an excel file is. Only one system has to do this job. And later that data is imported into sql server. This data can be imported directly, but i need both the steps.

Comment: As others have said, there really isn't a reason to get the path when a user uploads a file.  This question should probably be closed.