# Select a data input file using file chooser

Tags: java, jsp

Here is the full question as I've asked a small bit in my previous question [Get a path value in java file from html/jsp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35795619/get-a-path-value-in-java-file-from-html-jsp), Here I basically have the input file as an Excel sheet, this sheet acts as the source Database, and This file changes everyday as there would be a fresh Excel sheet sent. Right now I'm directly using the code as below.

```
public class DBConnection {
    private Connection conn, conn1;
    private Statement stmt;
    private ResultSet rs;
    private PreparedStatement ps, ps1;
    private String excelPath = "D:/MyScouceExcel.xls";
}
```

But instead of this, I want to try to give a File Chooser in my Index page and a button (as shown below), when I select that file and hit the button, the `excelPath` should be set to that path.

```
<input type="file" id="inputFile" name="inputFile"/>
<input type="button" value="set"/>
```

I don't want to upload file, Just the path is enough.

In the Java class, I know how to handle the excel data since I've worked on [Apache-poi](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/apache-poi/info). All I need to know is how can I pass this path. Please let me know How can I do this.

Thanks

Comment: Filechooser shows client computer's directories. But you want to choose a path from server. İt may work on development phase but it won't work on production. Are you sure?

Comment: Hi @Yusuf, Yes,. please let me know how to do it.

Comment: That is not as easy as you think :( You need to use javascript and java together.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope below codes work for you. First you need a servlet to read file structure of the server; You may need to edit below code to fix as your needs;

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

@WebServlet(urlPatterns = { "/serverpath" })
public class ServerPath extends HttpServlet {

    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

        String link = "<li><a href=\"serverpath?path=%s\">%s</a>&nbsp;<input type=\"button\" value=\"select\" onclick=\"window.opener.document.getElementById('path').value = '%s'; window.close();\" /></li>";
        response.setContentType("text/html");
        try {
            String path = req.getParameter("path");
            if (path == null) {
                // take disk drives, for linux / is enough for me
                response.getOutputStream().print(String.format(link, "/", "/", "/"));
            } else {
                File file = new File(path); //read clicked file path and its sub paths.
                if (file.isDirectory()) {
                    File[] subDir = file.listFiles();
                    for (File file2 : subDir) {
                        if (file2.isDirectory()) {
                            response.getOutputStream().println(
                                    String.format(link, file2.getAbsolutePath(), file2.getAbsolutePath(), file2.getAbsolutePath()));
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

Example of a html/jsp page;

```
<input type="text" id="path" />
<input type="button" value="Select" onclick="window.open('serverpath', '', 'width=700,height=500,top=150,left=150,scrollbars=yes,location=no')">
```

[image]

Comment: Hi Yusuf, Thanks for this. I'll try it.